# How to make infinite animation

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-animatable

How can you make moving image animation which won't stop but loops when it reaches the end of the screen and starts from another end?
Example gif:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it looks like multi-layers of images.
It will be complex by z-indexing and png images non-background.

Basically, the animation repeated infinitely will be something like that:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/1600x800") repeat 0 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -3200px 0; /* image width X 2 */
  }
}
```